# What graph theoretic methods which can identify groups?

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

Given a social graph, for instance, from Twitter, I want to identify *groups*.  Here I define *groups* as any highly connected (although not necessarily complete) subgraph.  What algorithms or methods exist that could help me here?

Comment: Maybe a good definition of group would be your first step; are groups disjoint (then you are looking for an equivalence relation)? If not, maybe you have a definition like "a group is a collection of people, such that any person knows at least k other people in the group" or similar...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you take a look at the paper [Fast Unfolding of Communities in Large Networks](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476). It gives a natural definition of what you mean by a group (a subgraph where the members are highly connected to each other, and non-members are not strongly connected to members) and then gives a fast algorithm for detecting such groups.

As a bonus, the algorithm produces as its output a graph of groups, with edges indicating the strength of connection between different groups. You can then apply the algorithm again to the new graph, and so forth, generating a hierarchical community structure for your network.

Comment: This looks very close to what I want.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for what's called "cluster analysis." The Wikipedia article on the topic may be a good place to start. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis

Comment: Nope, not really what I'm looking for.  Cluster analysis takes into account similarity, but not connection.